# Generate the coordinates of the circle radius to the coordinates in KML

Tags: java, kml

I have the coordinates of the circle center and the radius. I need to know the coordinates of the circle in order to posttroit circle in KML.

I wrote a script that generates a lower position, but he makes them when inserted into KML me out elips rather than a circle. Help to understand what's what?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Codechef
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
int[] a = new int[10];
double[] ar1;
double  ar2[];
    a[1]=5;

    double centerLat = (44.507693* Math.PI) / 180.0;  //rad
    double centerLng = (34.152739* Math.PI) / 180.0; //rad        
    double dist = 1/ 6371.0; 
    double lan;
     for (int x = 0; x <= 360; x += 1)
    {
        double brng = x * Math.PI / 180.0;         //rad
        double latitude = Math.asin(Math.sin(centerLat) * Math.cos(dist) +    Math.cos(centerLat) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(brng));
        double longitude = ((centerLng + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) *   Math.sin(dist)* Math.cos(centerLat), Math.cos(dist) - Math.sin(centerLat) 
        * Math.sin(latitude))) * 180.0) / Math.PI;
        lan=(latitude * 180.0) / Math.PI; //, longitude));
        System.out.println(""+lan+"  "+longitude );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: really it's incomprehensible - but if you show the equations you are trying to implement we might be able to see

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is correct. Here is complete Java code to generate the coordinates for a circle and output as a KML placemark with polygon geometry.

```
public class Codechef {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double centerLat = Math.toRadians(44.507693);
    double centerLng = Math.toRadians(34.152739);
    double diameter = 1; // diameter of circle in km
    double dist = diameter / 6371.0; 

    // start generating KML
    System.out.println("<kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\">\n"+
        "<Placemark><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>");

    for (int x = 0; x <= 360; x ++)
    {
        double brng = Math.toRadians(x);
        double latitude = Math.asin(Math.sin(centerLat) * Math.cos(dist) + Math.cos(centerLat) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(brng));
        double longitude = 
        centerLng + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(dist)* Math.cos(centerLat), Math.cos(dist) - Math.sin(centerLat)
            * Math.sin(latitude)) ;
        System.out.printf(" %f,%f", Math.toDegrees(longitude), Math.toDegrees(latitude));
    }
    System.out.println("</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>");
    System.out.println("</Placemark></kml>");
    }

}
```